# Why does DBAN crash on my HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, dban

I am using DBAN to erase HDD. DBAN is loaded from a CD and BIOS Boot order has been set to favour CD drive. On starting laptop, system boots from CD and DBAN interface can be seen. DBAN detects two storage devices, HDD and the SD Card. My HDD IS 320GB but DBAN says 298GB. It erases the SD card but when i try to erase HDD, it gives following error.

```
DBAN finished with non-fatal errors.
*ERROR /dev/sdb (process crash)
*ERROR /dev/sda (process crash)
```

Comment: When DBAN says "298GB", it means 298GiB, which is equal to 320GB.

Comment: What are you loading DBAN from? And how are you loading it? (Boot menu? Changed BIOS boot order?)

Comment: I edited the question to answer your queries, kindly read it again, thanks.

Comment: Get another DBAN. Doesn't work? Get another computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disconnect everything other than the drive you want to wipe and the keyboard (if using a PC).
2. Fire it up (F4) then select the method
3. Wipe(F10)